# How to add dynamically scrollbar based on other panel's scrollbar?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

first go through my demo program .

[image]

In the above image component hierarchy is
JFRAme will contain
JSplitPane
In both the split[Horizontal] there are JFXPanels
Each JFXPanel contains ScrollPane[javafx]

Now, you can see from the image that right side panel contains horizontal scrollbar which upwards[as the same value as the height of the scrollbar] the JFXPanel's contents.
Whereas in the left side panel no scrollbar is there.

My requirement is while resizing the window[through minimize, maximize, dragging the window... whatever] both the panel's contents must be in alignment. And to do so both the panel's should have horizontal scrollbars not either one.

Now the left panel is not resizable , so in any case of resizing the window only right side panel gets resized .

So while resizing the window how do I recognize that scrollbar should get added in the left panel ?
Moreover, I know how to add the the scrollbar but the important thing is where should I place that code so it will execute only when resizing the window ?

Comment: Does binding the `visibilityProperty` of both the `horizontal scrollbars` help?

Comment: Does binding the visibleProperty() will work on the ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED constraint. I mean I have implemented biDirectional binding on vertical scrollbars which has the ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS constraint......

Comment: Anyways I tried through binding the visibleProperty() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It's a bit of a hack: for one, you have to use a lookup to get the scrollbar; and also I have to assume the `ScrollPane` implementation just sets the scrollbar's visible property to show/hide it (as opposed to adding and removing it from the scene graph, for example).

This is example is all JavaFX, no Swing, but I think it should translate very easily to your context. I tested this under Java 8, I think there it should compile under Java 7 with JavaFX 2.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwoScrollPanes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final SplitPane split = new SplitPane();
        final ScrollPane scrollPane1 = makeScrollPane(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        final ScrollPane scrollPane2 = makeScrollPane(250);


        // if you want the vertical scrollbars to scroll in unison:
        scrollPane1.vminProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane2.vminProperty());
        scrollPane1.vmaxProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane2.vmaxProperty());
        scrollPane1.vvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane2.vvalueProperty());

        split.getItems().addAll(scrollPane1, scrollPane2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(split, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Node rightHorizScroller = null ;
        for (Node n : scrollPane2.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar) n;
            if (sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                rightHorizScroller = sb ;
            }
        }

        if (rightHorizScroller != null) {
            scrollPane1.hbarPolicyProperty().bind(
                    Bindings.when(rightHorizScroller.visibleProperty())
                        .then(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS)
                        .otherwise(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER));
        }
    }

    private ScrollPane makeScrollPane(double minLabelWidth) {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        VBox content = new VBox();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            Label label = new Label("Item "+i);
            label.setMinWidth(minLabelWidth);
            content.getChildren().add(label);
        }
        scrollPane.setContent(content);
        return scrollPane ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```